# Open sourcing a project that depends on libraries with various permissive licenses

Tags: licensing, license-notice

I am currently in the process of open sourcing a university work project on GitHub. The project is a Java library which depends on a couple of open source libraries which are licensed under different permissive licenses.

Our library is supposed to be licensed under the Apache 2.0 license. The libraries which the project depends on are licensed as:

- Apache 2.0
- MIT
- Eclipse Public License 1.0

This is my first time open sourcing a project and dealing with licensing, so i want to make sure i get everything right. If i researched correctly, all of these licenses are compatible with the Apache 2.0 license we are aiming at.

What i am struggling with is what i have to do in order for my dependencies to be used in the project. Do i create a top-level folder that contains all of the licenses besides Apache 2.0? Do i need to create some kind of list with all the libraries that i used?

---

**Note**: I did not alter any of the dependencies source code. I found the phrase "derivative work" a lot on the web. Is it also a derivative work if i only depend on the library?

Comment: Yes, "derivative work" is to be understood in a very broad sense.